# How do I lower current usage on a 12 VDC fan hooked to a battery without a rheostat?

Tags: battery-charging, current-limiting, solar-energy

I have a 12 V fan hooked to a battery. I also have a solar charger to charge the battery. The issue I have is that the fan runs very fast when the battery is fully charged and runs the battery down before the solar panel can keep it up.

I need something to lower the fan's current draw so it uses less than the solar is putting back in.

I don't think I want a rheostat because that burns up the extra voltage. I don't want to burn it, I want to pull less. What's my fix? I have two 50 W solar panels trying to charge and they can't keep up with the fan usage.

Comment: You could use a buck converter.

Comment: I’m gonna suggest something non-electrical: inlet throttling. Block off the intake and it should use less power.

Comment: @Bryan  trimming the blades shorter would also work, anything that allows the fan to spin faster.

Comment: Maybe you could add another solar panel?

Comment: You can also buy a different fan. Something designed for low power draw (e.g. HA60151V3) uses less than half the current compared to random cheap 12V fan moving the same amount of air.

Comment: I have already added a second solar panel to recharge battery. But the fan is pu

Comment: I have already added a second Solar panel. But the fan is still pulling to much current. The whole set up is in my hunting cabin. Not electricity.  I'm getting mildew build up so I put a fan in window to move air. I had in mind I would add a deep cycle battery so it would run day and nigh not just when the sun was on solar panels. But when the batt is full charge the fans runs strong running battery down. The 2 solar panels can't keep up with the fan draw. I need to reduce the draw.

Comment: I got the set up from amtrek Solar fan on amazon. I have pics of the set up but I'm not computer literate lol

Comment: If the fan still starts and runs at 6V: add a similar fan in series.

Comment: I believe your problem in the hunting cabin should be addressed differently:  Checking and **controlling the RH** of you cabin. I suggested 2-3 concepts, including a data from a Psychrometric charts. And paradoxically, promoting a stronger circulation from time to time, to avoid dead/wet spots. It seems your fan motor may be too big for the energy available, but using variable duty cycle might solve it too. I updated my answer to reflect all this, but maintained Original Post, as it is useful for your original question - and the update/supplement too.

Answer (score 11):

Use a PWM fan controller. You can find these on the interwebs (they’re a popular accessory for PC builders seeking to reduce noise), or build one yourself using a FET switch and a 555 timer.

Another trick is that sometimes higher voltage fans can run on lower voltage supplies (24V fan on 12V, say) at reduced speed and power draw.

And finally, a lower RPM / lower CFM fan will draw less power. Again, a popular solution for quiet PC folks.

MORE: I note from the comments that you’re using an ‘Amtrak’ (yes, it’s actually spelled Amtrak, surprised they get away with it) house fan kit. These fans are much bigger than the typical PC fan: 50W or more, intended to be powered by a large panel. Your PWM solution will also need to be bigger, and it won’t necessarily be something you could source from Amazon, Alibaba, etc. You could try.

Or you could add a bigger panel and increase your battery.

Might be able to repurpose a PWM driver for a car radiator fan. Car fans are similarly sized to your Amtrak unit; the controller accepts 12V-level PWM drive. Something like this for example: https://www.currentperformance.com/shop/pwm-e-fan-add-on-module/

Comment: Be aware that electric motors rely on air cooling and reducing their speed can cause them to burn out.

Comment: Not likely - the fan running slower also means less power shed in the motor.

Comment: yes, but it's non-linear. The change in the cooling effect of the flow will be more (or less) than the change in power.

Answer (score 7):

### Update / Supplement - Mildew and Fan management

From what is seen in the comments of OP, that said:

> The whole set up is in my hunting cabin. Not electricity. *I'm getting mildew build up* so I put a fan in window to move air. I had in mind I would add a deep cycle battery so it would run day and nigh not just when the sun was on solar panels.
> But when the batt is full charge the fans runs strong running battery down. The 2 solar panels can't keep up with the fan draw. I need to reduce the (current) draw.

A few points can be discussed, with information so far:

1. DC fan could be running from 12V with the equivalent of 4h of peak power of Solar power, during 24 h. Average consumption if then 50W/12V x 4h/24h = 0.7A continuously.
2. For this there are several examples of really powerful as these examples: [Sanyo 9CRE0412P5J06 12V 1.4A server fan air blower](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004189526588.html?spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.2.139eLA6jLA6jc3&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21BRL%21R%24%2099%2C14%21R%24%20100%2C93%21%21%21%21%21%402101f6b916626727201263406ec34e%2112000028327852210%21btf&_t=pvid%3Af088f6e3-c8e1-428c-826e-e21b16d7df69&afTraceInfo=1005004189526588__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1662672720&gatewayAdapt=glo2bra) or [Universal 7/9/10/12 Inch 12V 80W 2100RPM Car Air Conditioning Electronic Cooling Fan](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3256803637283542.html?spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.24.221fGGEUGGEUld&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21BRL%21R%24%2066%2C51%21R%24%2050%2C08%21%21%21%21%21%402101f6b916626725883698823ec34e%2112000027277892118%21btf&_t=pvid%3A901446e1-3061-4cfe-93be-56e9d1ccfb13&afTraceInfo=1005003823598294__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1662672588&gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt).  All of them are very powerful, but will demand a too high consumption.
3. Probably your fan uses a *brushless DC motor*, where current consumption (A) is not reduced proportionally to voltage. So, even if you reduce from 12V to 6V, current consumption will *not* be the half.
4. My suggestion here is to drive the fan depending of air moisture level - exactly to avoid mildew growth. For humid or rainy days, or when your are inside (exhaling air at 100% RH), humidity increases and would require more frequent air renewal. During hotter hours of the day, air ventilation could be more intermittent.

Check if you can use a fan not so power-hungry, draining significantly less than guesstimated 0.7A. There are several fans 80mm sized, that would require 0.1A at 12V, but may be too weak. You may find models that run at more than 3000rpm with consumption of 0.4A as [this here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2251832697252441.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5932de555hIbP2&algo_pvid=fca85ae0-10f8-48a8-a657-19bf84286c25&aem_p4p_detail=202209081543593058361852111950002346264&algo_exp_id=fca85ae0-10f8-48a8-a657-19bf84286c25-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265569239599%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21USD%2110.0%219.2%21%21%21%21%21%40210318b816626770391343671ebba7%2165569239599%21sea&curPageLogUid=FYZClclbHvsS&ad_pvid=202209081543593058361852111950002346264_1). Then operate it considering what is described ahead.

**Suggestions for fan operation to avoid mildew growth**:

Use a Moisture / Relative humidity sensor to check and control the operation of the Fan motor. This can be done with *analog* electronics loosely [inspired by circuits as this one](https://www.electroschematics.com/humidity-control-switch/), or using an Arduino-like solution, as [illustrated and explained here](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/LIMPINGLIM/humidity-sensor-controlled-bathroom-exhaust-fan-27131f).
You could even try an indirect RH measurement using the properties of **Wet & Dry bulb temperatures** - a “classic” way of measurement RH - the following table was obtained from this [article here](https://www.seaford.k12.ny.us/cms/lib/NY01000674/Centricity/Domain/684/Dewpoint%20Relative%20Humidity%20How%20To.pdf), marking several regions depending of its likelihood to develop mold.

[image]

**About RH and Mildew Growth**:
[This site](https://indoorscience.com/blog/relative-humidity-and-mold/) has a discussion that recommends the Relative Humidity (RH) to be lower than 60% (green) to avoid mildew and if above 80% (red), it would be more likely to grow. I also marked the table with a yellow zone, for less than ideal, but still manageable to control mildew.

After studying your needs, they are somewhat different than what you asked - and I answered in the Original Answer (ahead), but as it may be still applicable (and was already voted, I will leave the original.

**Updated Suggestions**:
(1) Use another fan draining up to 0.4A for 1 panel of 50W and
(2) Try to use a fan controlled by RH in your cabin. Possibly even an ON-OFF control with variable duty cycle - for example from 1 to 9 minutes ON, for every 10 min (10% to 90% duty cycle).
I believe a ***longer** Cycle Period* of a few minutes running each time, would always assure a minimum of air circulation in the cabin, *avoiding cold/wet spots*, and promoting higher average flow when is needed to purge a more humid air.

### Original Post - Reducing Fan Motor Speed

**There are at least 2 ways**, to regulate motor speed, while not dissipating energy as heat (linear regulator or “rheostat”):

1. **Use of a DC-DC converter module** called “**buck** converter” or “**step-down** converter”. Depending of the current capability there are ones based on the LM2596 as [this said to go up to 3A](https://www.addicore.com/lm2596-module-p/ad281.htm) or [based on XL4015](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LOG4XC0), said to go up to 5A. There are larger modules up to [12A as this one here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071CWMRYD), among others.
   My suggestion is to use **forced cooling** (fan/blower) over it, if operating current is **above 30~40%** of rated capacity, and to not use continuously with currents above 70~80%, even with forced cooling.
2. **Use a PWM-based circuit**, to work as a dimmer for the DC motor. In this case, the circuit can de designed to use the rotor inductance to smooth the current oscillations. But if frequency is too low, current may oscillate significantly above / below mean value (as if battery operated). Other devices connected nearby may not like these voltage fluctuations and electro-magnetic noise.

**The Buck-converter** - first option - has the advantage of providing a smoother operation, as it delivers a DC constant value. So, if the motor runs at 6V (low speed) and requires just 1A, the current drained from the 12V battery is about 1/2 = 0.5A, if assuming an idealistic and simplistic 100% efficiency.

**For the PWM-based circuit**, depending of the base-frequency chosen, it can be audible or not. Here, there is a possibility the motor may drain short pulses of higher current, depending of the frequency, rotor inductance and inertia of the spinning parts (rotor+blades).
In this scenario, the current at same speed of 6VDC can be the same as the Buck converter = 0.5A, or can be pulses of 1.0A, with 50% duty cycle, averaging at same “ideal average” of 0.5A. The difference then depends how the circuit and loads are matched to work together.

**Protection diodes**: On both cases, don’t forget to use flywheel diodes, like those used when switching relays, and rated for the same current of the motor. Use a first one (cathode on +Motor, anode to -Motor) and a second one from the output of the converter (anode) bleeding back to the input (cathode). This second on will only work when you turn-off the input power (intentionally or due to power failure), while the spinning parts and motor temporarily behave as a DC generator.

**My vote**: If motor current and voltage are  compatible with the ready-made Buck-converters, that would be my first choice, simpler for most people. However, if voltages and/or currents are too high, a dedicated project  PWM-based is simpler to be designed and fine-tuned.

Comment: If a PWM motor controller does a good job of bridging inductive currents with minimal voltage drop during the "off" portion of each cycle, its behavior will be essentially equivalent to that of a buck converter which uses an inductor equal to the motor's natural inductance, but without a need for a manual inductor.  Modulating the current to a brushless DC motor driver, however, may not yield the intended result if the driver effectively open-circuits the motor when the input voltage goes to zero.

Comment: @supercat, by broader points of view, I agree with you, as there is an “if”. That is why I said it will depend of the frequency and inductance of the motor. However, there is a answer commenting to use a LM555 + power FET, so frequency would not be that high as 100~300KHz, from a Buck module. Lower frequencies as 1KHz~10KHz, give good control speed, but current would be then limited by motor BEMF & resistance. In this case, there would be peaks of current, interleaved with Off-time spin-down.  About the *Brushless-DC*, I also see the same; and commented on the OP exactly about that.

Comment: Many buck mode power supplies are designed to be usable with inductors that are smaller than typical motors, and the 555 timer can go up to about 100,000Hz.  The big issue I see would be with the fact that many fans have brushless drivers built into them, the characteristics of which may not be amenable to PWM modulation of their power source.

Comment: @supercat, I have some brushless fans from PC casings (12V), laptop heatsink (5V) and have used either linear regulators (linearly variable per temperature) and also shifting the trimpot of those LM2596 modules. Both of them work. Tone “problem” I ever observed is on their curve U x I is aprox. linear, but far from proportional.  So, I just do this propositional speed control to minimize **noise** whenever possible, but in terms of flow **CFM** per Voltage & Current, low speed is quite inefficient. See my Update supplement, where I discuss **RH & Mildew** and a longer cycle run for fan motor.